# Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that I have been using for a long time and it stopped working on monday. No changes were made to the spreadsheet and I don't understand why I'm getting this error now.
Essentially the script sends an email when there is a change on column 16, which is the control column. In the file there is information about orders that get to the warehouse and whether or not they pass quality control. If they don't pass it, we receive an email stating that that specific order did not pass quality control.
Variable Ficha, which is column 23, has the FileID for every order, which is then attached in the email.
I have tried to write the variable "ficha", which seems to be the one causing the problem, in two different ways but I get the same error.
I tried the var ficha you can see in the script and also:

```
var ficha1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("CONTROL DE CALIDAD").getRange("W3:W").getValues(); 

  var ficha = ficha1.reduce(function(ar, e) {
    if (e[0]) ar.push(e[0])
    return ar;
  }, []);
```

With both variables I get the FileId (which is in column W) but when I try to get the File by ID it doesn't work. Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?
Thank you so much in advance!

The script is:

````
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var responses = ss.getSheetByName("CONTROL DE CALIDAD");
  var mail = ss.getSheetByName("MAIL");
  var active_range = responses.getActiveRange();
  var control = responses.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 16).getValue();
  var prenda = responses.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 5).getValue();
  var codigo = responses.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 4).getValue();
  var explicacion = responses.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 15).getValue();
  var num_taras = responses.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 14).getValue();
  var uds_revisadas = responses.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 13).getValue();
  var ficha = responses.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 23).getValue();
  var attachment = DriveApp.getFileById(ficha);```
````

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Consider sharing a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, or at least clarify the data structure. Under what context are these two scripts executed?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was my bad! I tried to explain it a bit, if it's still not clear let me know

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the user executing this doesn't have access to that file, or that the fileId has a typo and doesn't correspond to a file. Can you please double-check whether that's the case?

Comment: I have now double-checked both and they don't seem to be the problem, I also thought about it before and had checked already

Comment: I thought about using the URL instead of the ID and see if that solved it so I'm trying to find a way to make that work

Comment: I would suggest you wrap your code in a try catch block and see if any error isoccuring.  I question the value of this `var active_range = responses.getActiveRange();` because it is not the active sheet.  You use this `var responses = ss.getSheetByName("CONTROL DE CALIDAD");` to get an instance of another sheet.